# Не могу понять на какую библиотеку ругается

Tags: android, android-library

Ошибки:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.qwe, PID: 17729
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method getFont(Landroid/content/Context;ILandroid/util/TypedValue;ILandroid/widget/TextView;)Landroid/graphics/Typeface; in class Landroid/support/v4/content/res/ResourcesCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat' appears in /data/app/com.example.qwe-2/base.apk)
 at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getFont(TintTypedArray.java:119)
 at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.updateTypefaceAndStyle(AppCompatTextHelper.java:208)
 at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatTextHelper.java:110)
 at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelperV17.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatTextHelperV17.java:38)
 at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:81)
 at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:71)
 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:103)
 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1024)
 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1081)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:708)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:839)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:802)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:519)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
 at com.example.qwe.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)
 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6303)
 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2402)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2509)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:153)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1373)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5527)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
11-26 22:52:17.209 17729-17729/com.example.qwe E/MQSEventManagerDelegate: failed to get MQSService.
```

build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/maven2'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.qwe"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0'
    compile 'org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:20.50.533.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.0'
}
```

Как исправить?

Comment: На чем запускаете? API level?

Comment: И еще buildToolsVersion озвучьте, пожалуйста.

Comment: [Попробуйте сделать как описано тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47113948/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-no-static-method-getfontlandroid-content-contexti)